# Compilation linking with libncurses fail with "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, ncurses, linker-errors

I've just installed `ncurses` from sources, and the Makefile log make it looks like everything is OK. Both `libncurses.a` and `libncurses++.a` are present and using `-lncurses` or `-lncurses++` won't raise "cannot found -lX" errors.

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*curses*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Feb 19  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.a -> libncurses.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Feb 19  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.so -> libncurses.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 298812 Feb 19  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 171456 Feb 19  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     31 Feb 19  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
```

Strangely, when trying to compile a dummy sample like

```
#include <cursesapp.h>
#include <cursesm.h>
#include <cursesf.h>

int main() {
    NCursesPanel *mystd = new NCursesPanel();

    return 0;
}
```

with `g++ src/main.cpp -o main -lncurses++` will throw a really long list of linking errors inside `libcurses++`. Linking with an extra `-lncurses` won't help either. A small excerpt:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++.a(cursesw.o): In function `NCursesWindow::initialize() [clone .part.11]':
(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `noecho'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++.a(cursesw.o): In function `NCursesWindow::scanw(char const*, ...)':
(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `vwscanw'
```

I found it weird that the error messages point to `/usr/lib/gcc/5` and thought that maybe there are two `libncurses` on my machine, but I couldn't find it.

Is there really a problem of multiple `ncurses` on my machine? How can I investigate further and solve the linking problem?

Comment: have you tried `g++ src/main.cpp -o main -lncurses++ -lncurses` in that order?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, the result is the same as with `-lncurses` before, or just without it.

Comment: IDK why I was downvoted, is there a way to improve the question?

Comment: seems that you reversed the downvotes! good job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The official C++ interface may actually require that you link with all ncurses extra libraries, namely Menu, Panel, and Forms. The following solved the problem:

`g++ file.cpp -lncurses++ -lmenu -lpanel -lform -lutil -lncurses`

#### Follow the Demo

Looking at the c++ code [online](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/tree/master/c%2B%2B) I realized that it comes with a `demo.cc` and inspecting the `make` process it is clear that the demo is compiled. Because the installation went smoothly, I knew that the build process was capable of compiling so I should be too.

The complete command issued in the `make` was:

`g++  -o demo ../objects/demo.o -L../lib -lncurses++ -L../lib -lform -lmenu -lpanel -lncurses    -lutil    -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../c++ -I. -I../include  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -O2`

So after replacing the object with the actual source file, I started removing flags and arguments until it broke the compilation. Turns out `libcurses++` depends on those.